# web application noob question, python version 3.11.6 will not work with heroku-22

Tags: python, heroku, server

```
Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Requested runtime 'Python-3.11.6' is not available for this stack (heroku-22).
remote:  !     For supported versions, see: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 
#whole lotta numbers
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 
#whole  lotta numbers
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a     different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
```

Reminder, I am a complete noob.

I dont know why this version of heroku will not work with this version of python. Initially the stack was on herok-20 for some reason and switched stack to heoku-22 and then got warning, same version of this code has already been built.

Comment: Have you tried it with a lowercase `p`?

Comment: Oh, in runtime? Ill try it